# Manually type sql to map to c# object just like .Include("") method

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

To Make this simple here are example models. My models consist of a teacher with many students.

```
public class Teacher
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public Teacher()
        {
            Students = new List<Student>();
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TeacherId")]
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Using EntityFramework I could easily get all teachers and their students using linq

```
context.Teachers.Include("Students");
```

However, if I am working with a large model set where I need to include many child properties this query can take some time.

My sub question is if I were to chain this linq statement and select a new viewmodel with only the teacher properties I need and then select all the students into my student view model with only the properties I need and so on..
Would this be as efficient as writing the sql manually? Does Entityframework add overhead?

Now getting to my real question. How would I write this query manually to include child properties and return it in a way it would automatically bind to my viewmodels?

Example:

```
select Teacher.Id, Teacher.Name, Student.Id, Student.Name
from Teachers
inner join Students on Teacher.Id = Student.TeacherId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you wouldn't be using `Include` at all, you'd just be using `Select`:

```
var query = context.Teachers.Select(teacher => new 
{
    teacher.Id,
    teacher.Name,
    Students = teacher.Students.Select(student => new
    {
        student.Id,
        student.Name,
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I've been doing this for so long and always used include. Thanks! From a performance stand point if this was a massive model and I was returning a large data set with many joins would you write it like this or would you recommend writing manual sql to tweak for best performance? When I see entity framework generated code it is filled with tons of unions so I always write it manually and it performs so much faster.

Comment: I am using this linq statment:
context.Tables.Select(t => new TableQViewModel() { Title = t.Name }).Where(t => t.ProjectId == projectId)

The problem is ProjectId is not in my Select. It is not in my select because projectId is not in my viewmodel. Is there a solution besides adding it directly to my viewmodel?

Comment: @MIKE If you write the query in EF and it ends up performing below acceptable levels, then you may need to write the query in raw SQL.  It's usually best to wait until you actually have a problem before doing that though, most of the things that EF introduces that seem inefficient can be optimized out by the database itself.  Sometimes you do need to write the SQL yourself, but it should generally be pretty rare; if you find yourself doing it a *lot* there's problem something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @MIKE Do the `Where` before the `Select`.

Comment: If I add select after the where clause will it query every single column bind them all to my model then call select to get the properties I want and create a view model and bind them to my view model? Or will generate the sql properly and only select what was selected and only bind to my viewmodel?

Comment: @MIKE It's not going to pull the entire data set into memory if you're doing it properly.  If you're profiling the query and see that it is pulling back the whole data set you need to try to figure out what you're doing wrong in your query that's preventing it from being translated into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

for example, with anonymous types.

```
var q = from t in Teachers
select new {
    Id = t.Id,
    Name = t.Name,
    Students = t.Students.Select(x => new {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name
    })
};
```

But you can also declare DAO types.